# How can we select attachements based on Caption?

Tags: attachments, select

I am trying to select some attachements based on an attachement caption. I need to do this for a seperate download page. On the download page i want to display all attachment which caption equals "downloads".
So this way i can be selective of post attachments which can and can't be downloaded

At the  moment i have this code to select all the attached pdf's as downloable files, but i like to select some attached images and deselect some pdf's.

```
    $args = array('post_parent' => $atts['product_id'],
    'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'application/pdf', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
    //print_r($attachments);
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
...
$attachment->guid
```

i am also able to select images based on there given thumbnail name with

```
wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID,'product-slider-thumbnail')
```

but how to select based on caption??

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found a solution by using this in the loop

```
if ($attachment->post_excerpt == 'download') {
```

Where i have put "download" in the caption textfield.

hmmm, what if i want to select an image with 2 or more different captions?